# Windows 7 XPS Document Writer has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, printing, xps

I have successfully used the Windows 7 XPS Document writer for quite a while under windows 7 (64 bit).

Now however when i try to print i get prompted twice for the output file name and then get different error messages depending upon the application being used. e.g. Notepad gives a 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request'.

I have disabled and reenabled the XPS facilities of windows features and have similiarly removed and readded the printer.  But the end result is the same.

I've uninstalled all applications i have installed since the time when i know it worked but this also has not made any difference.

Suggestions please!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty simple, because I was having the same issue and fixed it. I have the same OS and XPS worked for a while, then suddenly stopped working.

Here is what you need to do:

- Go to *Devices and Printers*
- Select *XPS printer* and right-click
- From the options, select *Troubleshoot*.

Then the system will apply the necessary fix and set XPS to 'Default printer'. At this point, it is up to you to go with this preference. Once it's fixed; select XPS printer and right click and select 'Printer Properties' and perform 'Print a test page'.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [XPS downloads page](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/viewxps.mspx). There's the Microsoft XPS Essentials Pack which includes the software for generating XPS document.

You could try reinstalling that.

Comment: thanks - unfortunately the windows 7 option states "Windows 7 XPS Viewer is already installed on your system." with no option to download to reinstall.

Comment: @jamie - that's unfortunate. I was hoping there'd be a "repair" option at the very least.

Comment: in the end i have ended up re installing windows 7-problem sorted.